# Show dimensions of PNG-files in OS X Yosemite Finder preview

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, finder

I have a bunch of very similar images and would like for a quick way to see the dimensions of each image, without having to opening it first.

Finder does supports this natively, but for some reason it doesn't show the dimensions for some of my PNG images: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozuV8.png)

Others work.

Anyone know how to fix this? Plugin to Finder maybe?

Comment: They show up in my Finder on Yosemite and I only use the standard version. There must be some option if you press `Cmd+J` or `Cmd+,` in Finder.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. It's working now for the same files I had problems with earlier... Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the cause, but suddenly it started working again - might have just needed a reboot.